# Converting distance and time to pace

Tags: arithmetic

I am trying to work out pace by doing time / distance.  So for example if I run for for 39 minutes and cover 5 miles it gives me

39 / 5 = 7.8

This is correct but I want to result to be in minutes and seconds rather than a decimal.  So what I actually want back is 7.48.  I could also take the 0.8 and do

(60 / 100) * 80

But surely there is a way to do it in one calculation?

Answer (score 3):

Take the fractional part of your calculation of $7. 8$ minutes/mile, and multiply by $60$ to calculate the number of seconds this fraction of a minutes amounts to:

$$7 \;\mathrm{ minutes} + (0.8 \times 60 = 48\;\mathrm{seconds}.)$$

Hence, $7.8$ minutes/mile is equal to a $7$-minute, $48$-second mile.

This can also be done as a standard fraction: $$\dfrac{39\;\mathrm{minutes}}{5 \;\mathrm{miles}} = 7 + \frac 45 \;\text{minutes per mile} = 7 + \frac 45\times 60 = 7 \;\text{minutes}, 48\;\text{seconds per mile}$$

Comment: Note that there is no *direct way* aside from such a procedure outlined above. Even if you measure the time of the run in seconds and divide by 5 miles, you'd then need to follow up by dividing by 60 the total number of seconds per mile in order to determine the quotient (number of minutes), and remainder (in seconds).

Comment: Needs another TU! +1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to express with one single formula, you can write:
$$ \left \lfloor \frac{x}{y} \right \rfloor + \left ( \frac{x}{y}-\left \lfloor \frac{x}{y} \right \rfloor \right)\cdot 60 = $$

With your example, plugging in the numbers:

$$ \left \lfloor \frac{39}{5} \right \rfloor + \left ( \frac{39}{5}-\left \lfloor \frac{39}{5} \right \rfloor \right)\cdot 60 = $$

$$ 7 + (7.8 - 7)\cdot60=$$

$$7 + 0.8 \cdot 60 = 7.48 $$

where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the floor function.
Then, you have to remember that this result does not mean 7.48 minutes but 7 minutes and 48 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you are programming it then there is the concept of integer division
$$7/3=2$$ and remainder calculation (called Modulo) where $$7 modulo 3 = 1$$.
You can use these functions to display in one "sentence" minutes and seconds.